# PHP replace dynamic content based on position in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

**What I would like :**

The values to replace are between `{{`  `}}`.

**Input :** 
"this is letter {{ A }} and {{ B }}"

but it can change :          "this is letter {{ AAAA }} and {{ BBB }}"

> with array ("C", "D")

**Output :** "this is letter C and D

---

I don't know in advance the string between `{{` `}}` and I would like to extract those strings and replace them with another value :

**What I tried :**

```
$body = "This is a body of {{awesome}} text {{blabla}} from a book.";


//Only work if we know the keys (awesome, blabla,...)
$text["awesome"] = "really cool"; 
$text["blabla"] = "";
echo str_replace(array_map(function($v){return '{{'.$v.'}}';},    array_keys($text)), $text, $body);
```

**Result :**

```
This is a body of really cool text from a book.
```

**Problem :**

I cannot find something similar to this already asked (there is only when we know before the old content between brackets, but mines are "dynamic"), so the solution with **array_map** or **preg_replace_callback** doesn't work.

Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: So what is an example of your _actual_ problem and not what you _have_ solved? Do you want to execute code between `{{}}`, look up values from an object or what?

Comment: how many words are with `{{}}` in the string you want to replace? only 2

Comment: @chris85 yes it was marked as duplicate, I saw the links you gave but my question is different (even if very similar to what was already asked, I've read all answers before posting my question, nothing like my problem)

Comment: @user2486 they replace "test" with "test two", in my case I don't know "test"

Comment: @chris85 I know what value to replace because it's between {{ }}, so I want to replace "this is letter {{ A }} and {{ B }}"   using array ("C", "D")=> "this is letter C and D"

Comment: @chris85 yes exactly you understood, I maybe didn't explain correctly (I updated the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
$body = "This is a body of {{awesome}} text {{blabla}} from a book.";
$count = 0;
$terms[] = '1';
$terms[] = '2';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}/',function($match) use (&$count, $terms) {
    $return = !empty($terms[$count]) ? $terms[$count] : 'Default value for unknown position';
    $count++;
    return $return;
}, $body);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Ktaod

This will find each `{{}}` pairing and replace the value with a value from an array based on the position it was found in the string.

The regex `\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}` is just looking for 2 `{`s, anything in between, and then 2 `}`s.

Comment: FYI `preg_replace_callback` has an optional forth argument called `$count` which makes you avoid using an external counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$body = "This question is a {{x}} of {{y}} within SO.";

$text = ['possible duplicate', '@21100035'];

echo preg_replace_callback('~{{[^{}]++}}~', function($m) use ($text, &$count) {
    return $text[(int)$count++] ?? $m[0];
}, $body, -1, $count);

// Output
// This question is a possible duplicate of @21100035 from SO.
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Hhh8v)

Comment: but I don't know in advance x and y

Comment: @Julien : so how you will replace with string between `{{}}`  ? if you `don't know in advance x and y`

Comment: with sthg like that : 
array[0]="value to replace the first {{ }}";
 (0 replace the name of the text to replace that I don't know, but I know his position

Comment: @revo there is an error in the code you sent, did you succeed to fix it (in your live demo)?

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /in/Hhh8v on line 6"  @revo  (I tried to remove the double ??, then another error occure)

Comment: Coalescing operator `??` is new to PHP (>PHP 7.0). You can change it to ternary operator `? :` to work with older versions of PHP. @Julien

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$body = "This question is a {{x}} of {{y}} within SO.";

$searches = ['{{x}}', '{{y}}'];
$replaces = ['possible duplicate', '@21100035'];

echo str_replace($searches, $replaces, $body);

// Output
// This question is a possible duplicate of @21100035 from SO.
```

**EDIT: 
IF YOU DON'T KNOW X & Y THEN YOU CAN TRY THIS**

```
<?php

$body = "This question is a {{x}} of {{y}} within SO.";

preg_match_all('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/', $body, $matches);

$searches = $matches[0];
$replaces = ['possible duplicate', '@21100035'];

echo str_replace($searches, $replaces, $body);

// Output
// This question is a possible duplicate of @21100035 from SO.
```