# custom str_replace = find(same value) and replace with array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I wonder if it's possible to create my own str_replace,  to fill in the blank see example below:

```
$words = array('cat','mole');
$find='[blank]';
$string ="Lorem ipsum -[blank]- sit amet, consectetur
                        adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum augue 
                        sit amet blandit vehicula. Nullam placerat
                        aliquam dictum. Quisque elementum nisl
                        sed pellentesque elementum. Aliquam erat
                        volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas [blank]." 
echo str_replace ($find,$words,$string);
```

the expected out put would be this:

```
Lorem ipsum -cat- sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum augue 
sit amet blandit vehicula. Nullam placerat
aliquam dictum. Quisque elementum nisl
sed pellentesque elementum. Aliquam erat
volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas mole.
```

thanks

edit:  if i can improve this question i would  it hard to explain so i given a example instead.

Comment: You are TheDeveloper. You should know that everything is possible ;)

Comment: @Niels well not entirely true, some thing are a mystery

Comment: You can create any function you want...not sure why `$words` is an array though and find isn't, but that's a beauty of php, most functions were created after the fact

Comment: using `preg_replace_callback()`; you'll need to escape the $find with `preg_quote()` and then jut keep a count of which elements from $words have already been replaced, probably using `%` to cycle back through in case you find more $finds than there are $words in the array

Comment: Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378516/php-replace-dynamic-content-based-on-position-in-string/47378849#47378849.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Brief

A super simple way of doing this is simply iterating over the array and setting `preg_replace` to only replace 1 item (instead of every match). Another method uses string functions to find position of `$needle` in `$haystack` as adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252710/3600709).

---

### Code

Both methods below assume that `$haystack` is the input. Sample input (copied from OP's question) below:

```
$haystack = <<<DOC
Lorem ipsum -[blank]- sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum augue 
sit amet blandit vehicula. Nullam placerat
aliquam dictum. Quisque elementum nisl
sed pellentesque elementum. Aliquam erat
volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas [blank].
DOC;
```

#### Using regex

If your `$needle` is *unknown* in the sense that it can possibly contain special regex characters, you can use `preg_quote` to escape these special characters (as noted by [musashii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2953318/musashii) in the comments below my answer).

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/lasd9k)

```
$array = ['cat', 'mole'];
$re = '/\[blank\]/';

foreach($array as $replacement) {
    $text = preg_replace($re, $replacement, $haystack, 1);
}

echo $haystack;
```

#### Using string functions

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/hgeldj)

```
$array = ['cat', 'mole'];
$needle = '[blank]';

foreach($array as $replacement) {
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $haystack = substr_replace($haystack, $replacement, $pos, strlen($needle));
    }
}

echo $haystack;
```

Comment: you can use `preg_quote` for the needle
`$string= preg_replace("~".preg_quote($needle)."~", $replace, $string,1);`

Comment: +1 dangit, I was about to post the non-regex thing you added. Minor optimizations to that would be getting the length of needle once outside the loop and breaking if needle isn't found.

Comment: @Don'tPanic sorry! I stole the answers haha

Comment: @Jan ya I realize this only works well on a small subset. There's definitely room for optimizations, but I wanted to keep it simple to give the general idea of how to achieve the expected result.

Comment: @Jan you put that in your answer, so I'll leave that one for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another one could be to use `preg_replace_callback` and a closure:

```
$cnt = 0;
$regex = '~\Q[blank]\E~';
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($match) use ($cnt, $words) {
        global $cnt;
        if (array_key_exists($cnt, $words)) {
            $cnt++;
            return $words[$cnt-1];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    $string);
echo $string;
```

This yields

```
Lorem ipsum -cat- sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Donec condimentum augue 
sit amet blandit vehicula. Nullam placerat
aliquam dictum. Quisque elementum nisl
sed pellentesque elementum. Aliquam erat
volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas mole.
```

---

Idea is to increase a counter `$cnt` and return the value of the array `$words`.
The regular expression

```
~\Q[blank]\E~
```

just means `[blank]` without escaping it.

Comment: thanks, even more interesting approach.  Any performance downfall here, in comparisons to  `substr_replace` and `strpos`